# How to switch ApartmentState of a thread that has already been started

Tags: wpf, multithreading, servicestack, server-sent-events

I'm using ServiceStack's SSE feature in WPF as a chat mechanism. I have registered OnMessage method and in it I am creating a chat message view after receiving the appropriate message from server. I'm getting the "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this" exception which immediately made me assume that the calling thread wasn't my main thread and a quick debugging showed exactly that. SSE makes its own thread so it seems, and that thread ApartmentState isn't set to STA. What can I do to mitigate this problem?

Is using `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` a good and clean method for creating my views in this instance?

I've also considered making a new STA thread every time my `OnMessage` registered method is invoked, but it would mean creating a new thread on every chat message.

Comment: Switching is not possible.  STA is a term that WPF borrowed.  It actually means that you can't update UI components from a worker thread, WPF is not thread-safe.  Strictly separate computational work from UI updates, favor BackgroundWorker or TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() or async/await to segregate.  If you have to use Dispatcher.Invoke() for some reason then always favor BeginInvoke().